# How to over-write data and then sort or filter on that data?

Tags: sql, variables, sql-order-by

I need to write some SQL where I selectively over-write some data in a table, and then sort and/or filter on
the over-ridden data. Here's a much simplified example...

I have a table full of pet names called PET

```
PET_NAME   PET_SPECIES PET_PK
---------- ----------- -----------
Barney     Dog         {PETGUID1}
Fergus     Cat         {PETGUID2}
Meatball   Hamster     {PETGUID3}
```

I have another table that holds their life status called LIFE

```
LIF_PK     LIF_STATUS   LIF_PET_FK
---------- ------------ ------------
{LIFGUID1} Alive        {PETGUID1}
{LIFGUID2} Alive        {PETGUID2}
{LIFGUID3} Dead         {PETGUID3}
```

I want to report the pets and their life status.

```
SELECT          PET_NAME,
                PET_SPECIES,
                LIF_STATUS
FROM            PET
INNER JOIN      LIFE ON LIF_PET_PK=PET_PK
```

Where the pet is dead, I don't want to report the name, and just have 'DEADPET' instead.
Too many memories.
And then I want to order by pet names.

I thought I could create a proxy variable, and then set it to the pet name in a
case statement only when the pet was alive e.g.

```
DECLARE      @petName nvarchar(18)
SELECT       @petName=(CASE LIF_STATUS='Alive' THEN PET_NAME ELSE 'DEADPET' END),
             PET_SPECIES,
             LIF_STATUS
FROM         PET
INNER JOIN   LIFE ON LIF_PET_PK=PET_PK
ORDER BY     @petName
```

But I cannot do that, TSQL won't allow it.

In reality of course, this has nothing to do with Pets and is all to do with financial loans {Meatball Lives!}
but the principle is the same.

Comment: Would it work if you tried (CASE LIF_STATUS='Alive' THEN PET_NAME ELSE 'DEADPET' END) as `ABCD` and then ORDER BY `ABCD`

Comment: That might be it.  I had to use (CASE LIF_STATUS WHEN 'Dead' THEN 'DEADPET' ELSE PET_NAME END) because TSQL complained about the equals sign I used in the comparison, but this might well be the answer.

Comment: Let me know if that worked, I'll post it as an answer :)

Comment: Let's say yes, that's the answer.  Unfortunately I now have another knock-on problem, but in this case, it's good!  Thanks.

Comment: what's that? Good luck!

Comment: I now need to do strap on a 'WHERE PET_NAME='Fergus'' type clause, and I cannot use the on-the-fly column name, it only accepts the actual column name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26461/discussion-between-uchamp-and-steve-hibbert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following should work for you (also, incorporating your bug fix regarding the variable assignment):

```
SELECT       (CASE LIF_STATUS='Alive' THEN PET_NAME ELSE 'DEADPET' END) as `PET_NAME`
             PET_SPECIES,
             LIF_STATUS
FROM         PET
INNER JOIN   LIFE ON LIF_PET_PK=PET_PK
ORDER BY     `PET_NAME`
```

Comment: Weird, the question has been edited to 'over-write' instead of 'over-ride' which is what I intended.  I don't want to over-write data, that implies changing data in the database.  I want to over-ride data, with my own value, purely in the report.  Oh well, no big deal, not a great help though.

Comment: ah! I suggested that change because I thought you'd written that by mistake. You mention over-write a few times in the question detail. Hence, the edit. I think the title can be made clearer by mentioning over-write while querying. What do you think?

Comment: I don't mind, no biggie, and thanks for your help.  All the work I did on this was blitzed though, will have to do a nested select I think.  Live and learn...